# MySQL out of range value for decimal column

Tags: mysql, decimal, range

After searching, I found plenty of out of range problems with people not knowing that the first digit, m, in decimal(m,n) is the total amount of digits. However, that is not my problem.

For the column in question I have the following:

```
Field | Type                   | Null | Key | Default | Extra
preco | decimal(50,2) unsigned | NO   |     | 0.00    |
```

The setting decimal(50,2) is way more than I really want or need. I really only want 10 digits total. Its a price, so anything over 100 million is probably ridiculous, so decimal(10,2) would probably be more appropriate. However, MySQL Is not accepting the following query:

```
INSERT INTO `produto` (`tipo_id`, `preco`, `qtd`, `opcao1`) VALUES (110, '77888555.43', '10', 'Azul')
```

I tried the query through CodeIgniter, phpMyAdmin and directly in the MySQL command line client. I also tried it without the quotes on the decimal value but I always get the same error:

"Out of range value for column 'preco' at row 2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried it with [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php), it is working perfect. I tried to change both ways in [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php) directly through Table Data tab and using Query. It is just working. it seems there is no problem in Decimal Range, but problem is some where else. See the screenshots attached

Directly through Table Data Tab
[image: Directly through Table Data Tab]

Through insert query
[image: Through insert query]

Table Structure[image]

Hope it help...

Comment: Thanks. It looks like there is some problem with my particular MySQL application. As I said, I entered the query directly in the MyQSL command-line client, and while there, I ran "describe produto", and I got the exact results as described. So when you say "somewhere else," there really is nowhere else except for MySQL itself.

Comment: Something else that is strange here is that I can delete just one digit in the query '7888555.43' and MySQL accepts it.

Comment: So what do you think? Is it a MySQL bug?

Comment: By somewhere else, I mean problem is not there in query at all. What version of MySQL are you using? Can you try uninstalling and reinstalling MySQL again? If so, do take backup of your data!!!

Comment: I would vote up your answer because I appreciate your effort, but I don't have enough points yet to do that. Thanks!

Comment: I'll accept it, but I think my solution was better. I have 17 databases, one of which has over 100,000 records, so the idea of backing up everything didn't thrill me. It was much easier to just download one table, delete it and upload again.

Answer (score 2):

You are sending the value for `preco` as a string which is accepted by MySQL in the same way as a numerical value.